# Is there a way to present conjugate transpose of a Y Pauli rotation as a Cirq Operator?

Tags: programming, cirq, pauli-gates

Given:
Ry(theta) acting on one qubit

I'm trying to use existing Cirq Operators to build the conjugate transpose of the above gate. I need the operator to produce the exact unitary of the given gate for the given theta.

I'v already used cirq.optimizers.single_qubit_matrix_to_gates. It gives YPowGates but the global phase changes with theta. I need either the exact unitary of the gate or another conversion that its global phase does not change with theta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cirq.inverse(operation)` will return the conjugate transpose of an operation.

Equivalently, you can use `operation**-1` (this is the first thing that `cirq.inverse` tries).

For the specific case of $R_y$, you can just negate the angle i.e. use `cirq.ry(-theta)`.